# Resource of type unknown when passed to Guzzle's createRequest method

Tags: php, guzzle

When I pass a resource reference in the `body` element of the `$option` argument for `createRequest`, Guzzle 5.3.0 transforms the resource type `stream` into `unknown`. This makes the resource unusable and causes an exception from within Guzzle.

e.g.

```
$fp = fopen('path/to/a/file.txt');

$request = $client->createRequest('POST', $someUrl, ['body' => $fp]);
```

Just before `createRequest` the type of `$fp` would be `stream`. But after that line, `$fp` is of type `unknown`.

Guzzle is internally converting the stream to `GuzzleHttp\Stream` before sending the request, but somehow it is getting mangled every time.

This results in the exception `fstat(): 501 is not a valid stream resource` when `$client->send($request)` is called.

What could be causing this and how do I get around it?

Comment: You're missing a single-quote after `'POST`

Comment: Fixed the missing quote.

Comment: `$fp = Stream::factory( fopen('path/to/a/file.txt'));` Try with `Stream` object.  you need to add `use GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream;`

Comment: @jagad89 Explicitly converting it into `GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream` resolved the problem! Thanks! Please put that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Stream` object to create request.

First of all add Stream class

`use GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream;`

Create stream object from file and use it for creating request.

```
$stream = Stream::factory(fopen('path/to/a/file.txt'));

$request = $client->createRequest('POST', $someUrl, ['body' => $stream ]);
```

Comment: Could you please modify your answer here to reference `$stream = Stream::factory(fopen('path/to/a/file.txt'));` as in your comment? I think it will be clearer for anyone else seeking a similar solution.

Comment: Sorry!! I forget to apply actual solution.

Comment: Appreciate it! Apparently this crops up when there is a double request that references the same raw stream resource. For instance, if there is a signing request followed by an actual request.

Comment: I am wondering one thing. Do we need to call `fclose()` on file handler ? Or `Stream` class handle it.

Comment: This is actually not a solution but a workaround.